# sort array by key

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I make an `NSMutableArray(listId)` (through a call to a sqlite database) with  `dictionaries(dizionario)`:

```
-(void)readItems {
    NSString * query = @"SELECT * FROM item";
    NSArray * arrayQuery = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"id",@"title",@"note",@"icon",@"perc",@"complete",nil];
    NSArray * arrayEle = [self caricaValoriDaDBStandard:query :arrayQuery];

    for (int i = 0; i < [arrayEle count]; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dizionario = [arrayEle objectAtIndex:i];
        [listId addObject:dizionario];
    }
}
```

How do I sort the array, for example, for the "id" key?

Comment: Cleaned up your code a bit. Try not to use tabs in your code pieces on SO. Replace them with 4 spaces. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
NSArray sortedArray = [listId sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {
    NSString *first = [a objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *second = [b objectForKey:@"id"];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```

Comment: very nice! thanks! how do I choose to let it increasing or decreasing order?

Comment: @Vins Hope it will work! If so, do not forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: yep,still waiting for 2 minutes, there is a limit of time to do it :)